# filedialog, tkinter and opening files

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, global-variables, filedialog

I'm working for the first time on coding a Browse button for a program in Python3. I've been searching the internet and this site, and even python standard library.

I have found sample code and very superficial explanations of things, but I haven't been able to find anything that addresses the problem I'm having directly, or a good enough explanation so I can customize code to my needs.

Here is the relevant snippet:

```
Button(self, text = "Browse", command = self.load_file, width = 10)\
        .grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = W) .....


 def load_file(self):

    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = (("Template files", "*.tplate")
                                                         ,("HTML files", "*.html;*.htm")
                                                         ,("All files", "*.*") ))
    if filename: 
        try: 
            self.settings["template"].set(filename)
        except: 
            messagebox.showerror("Open Source File", "Failed to read file \n'%s'"%filename)
            return
```

The method is a hybrid of some code I found along the way with my own customizations. It seems like I finally got it to work (kinda), though its not exactly how I need it.

I get this error when I activate the 'Browse' button: `NameError: global name 'filedialog' is not defined`.

I've found fairly similar issues along the way but all the solutions suggested I have covered. I went into the 'filedialog' help section of IDLE but didn't glean anything from there either.

Would someone mind providing a break down and a little guidance on this; none of my books address it specifically, and I've checked all the solutions provided to others—I'm lost.

Comment: Have you imported it? `from tkinter import filedialog`

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The exception you get is telling you `filedialog` is not in your namespace.
`filedialog` (and btw `messagebox`) is a tkinter module, so it is not imported just with `from tkinter import *`

```
>>> from tkinter import *
>>> filedialog
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'filedialog' is not defined
>>>
```

you should use for example:

```
>>> from tkinter import filedialog
>>> filedialog
<module 'tkinter.filedialog' from 'C:\Python32\lib\tkinter\filedialog.py'>
>>>
```

or

```
>>> import tkinter.filedialog as fdialog
```

or

```
>>> from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
```

So this would do for your browse button:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter.messagebox import showerror

class MyFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.master.title("Example")
        self.master.rowconfigure(5, weight=1)
        self.master.columnconfigure(5, weight=1)
        self.grid(sticky=W+E+N+S)

        self.button = Button(self, text="Browse", command=self.load_file, width=10)
        self.button.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)

    def load_file(self):
        fname = askopenfilename(filetypes=(("Template files", "*.tplate"),
                                           ("HTML files", "*.html;*.htm"),
                                           ("All files", "*.*") ))
        if fname:
            try:
                print("""here it comes: self.settings["template"].set(fname)""")
            except:                     # <- naked except is a bad idea
                showerror("Open Source File", "Failed to read file\n'%s'" % fname)
            return


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyFrame().mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. You know, I messed around with importing them both from tkinter (just didn't get it exactly right), and because I wasn't getting it exactly right I was accrediting my mistake to somewhere I wasn't making a mistake. My question is: I thought that 'from tkinter import *' imported ALL of tkinter. so why do these have to be imported seperately? Can you point me towards some documentation about this? Thanks again

Comment: I didnt found any link with simple, to the point explanation. Maybe you have more luck. Check first python [reference](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement) and [docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages)

Comment: The opening sentence of this solution tells you why you need the two statements.  filedialog is a module, so it doesn't get imported with the "from tkinter import *", and has to be imported separately.

Answer (score 3):

I had to specify individual commands first and then use the `*` to bring all in command.

```
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
```

Comment: "from tkinter import filedialog"<br>
"from tkinter import *"

Comment: Nitpicking the nomenclature: These are modules, not commands.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try adding the self prefix to the fileName and replacing the method above the Button ? With the self, it becomes visible between methods.

```
...

def load_file(self):
    self.fileName = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = (("Template files", "*.tplate")
                                                     ,("HTML files", "*.html;*.htm")
                                                     ,("All files", "*.*") ))
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter is actually a python package, or a folder of python files. Check python source to find it. "tkinter.filedialog" is part of "tkinter.messagebox" Try "from tkinter.messagebox import filedialog" to get filedialog [python 3.7].