# Using Tkinter on OSX Mountain Lion 8.2

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm working on learning to make GUIs with Tkinter for Python programs and I have run into a bunch of problems:

Attempting to run `from Tkinter import filedialog` I get `ImportError: cannot import name filedialog`. Elsewhere I have seen it called with the lowercase `tkinter` (which I think is for Python 3 only) but it does not recognize that as existing `ImportError: No module named tkinter`. Yet running `from Tkinter import *` works and I'm able to create the sample hello world from the tutorial.

My only guess is that it is attempting to use an obsolete version of Tkinter that shipped with OSX. Yet considering how new Mountain Lion is, I have to wonder how obsolete it would really be. My assumption is that upon installing Python 2.7 myself, if I run from IDLE, it should work, but instead I get exactly the same thing above from the IDLE shell.

So after that I tried `sudo pip install tkinter` and `sudo pip install Tkinter` from the Unix terminal, but I get back `No distributions at all found for update`

So I start looking into documentation on Tkinter itself, and I come across [Tcl/Tk instructions for Mac OS X](http://www.python.org/getit/mac/tcltk/) which states:

> Important: If you are using Mac OS X 10.8, 10.7 or 10.6, use IDLE or tkinter from a 64-bit/32-bit Python installer only with ActiveTcl 8.5 installed. If you cannot install ActiveTcl 8.5, use a 32-bit-only installer instead.

So I find my OS in the table they provide and see that they recommend [ActiveTcl8.5.11](http://www.python.org/getit/mac/tcltk/#activetcl-8-5-11), but unfortunately, the [download link is broken.](http://downloads.activestate.com/ActiveTcl/releases/8.5.11.1/)

So I'm completely at a loss here. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to implement a File Dialog, have a look at [tkFileDialog](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/tkFileDialog). It is a seperate module & not part of Tkinter module.

You can use it by directly importing it:

```
import tkFileDialog
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get something to work, but I don't really understand it. I was looking at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9239514/filedialog-tkinter-and-opening-files) where filedialog is used as if it is a part of tkinter itself.

Comment: They've seem to have made changes to Tkinter in Pyton 3, like making it all lower case and making tkfiledialog part of tkinter module. That's the cause of confusion. I am still using 2.x :)