# Unexpected behavior with loading a module in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, tkinter

As far as I understood, `from module import *` means that everything from the module will be locally available.

In my code I found:

```
from tkinter import *
```

and

```
from tkinter import filedialog
```

Looking back, I figured I could drop this last line, but then it is unavailable:

```
NameError: name 'filedialog' is not defined.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: To keep it short, this is your answer: [filedialog is a **module** of tkinter][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9239514/filedialog-tkinter-and-opening-files

Comment: The `*` import does *not* import submodule. It simply imports the selected package and puts everything in the global namespace. There is no difference in "things loaded" between `import tkinter` and `from tkinter import *`, the difference is that the latter will pollute the namespace. If the `__init__.py` file does not import submodules then you *must* import them explicitly(and this seems the case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, Tkinter is a package (which means that it contains other modules).            From Tkinter import * will only give you the default modules.

from the documentation:

**6.4.1. Importing * From a Package**

> Now what happens when the user writes from sound.effects import *? Ideally, one would hope that this somehow goes out to the filesystem, finds which submodules are present in the package, and imports them all. This could take a long time and importing sub-modules might have unwanted side-effects that should only happen when the sub-module is explicitly imported.
>
> The only solution is for the package author to provide an explicit index of the package. The import statement uses the following convention: if a package’s **init**.py code defines a list named **all**, it is taken to be the list of module names that should be imported when from package import * is encountered. It is up to the package author to keep this list up-to-date when a new version of the package is released. Package authors may also decide not to support it, if they don’t see a use for importing * from their package. For example, the file sounds/effects/**init**.py could contain the following code:

Please, read the following post for another answer to your question.
[filedialog, tkinter and opening files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9239514/filedialog-tkinter-and-opening-files)