# Add multiple extensions in one filetypes mac - tkinter/filedialog/askopenfilename

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, filedialog

I am trying to use `tkinter.filedialog` to choose the file in Mac.

It works fine with one filetype in this way:

```
filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Excel files", "*.xlsx")])
```

However, I want to choose either `xlsx` or `xls` files. I searched and found a question [filedialog, tkinter and opening files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9239514/filedialog-tkinter-and-opening-files). I use the similar way but it does not work with Mac if I change to this:

```
filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Excel files", "*.xlsx; *.xls")])
```

How should I change to choose either `xlsx` or `xls` files in the file dialog?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

It seems that you must separate the wildcard patterns with a *space* rather than `;` (verified on Python 3.5.1):

```
from tkinter import filedialog

# add `, initialdir="..."` to set the initial directory shown in the dialog
filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Excel files", ".xlsx .xls")])
```

Note:

- While `"*.xlsx *.xls"` would work too (at least on Windows and macOS), the initial `*` isn't necessary.<sup>[1]</sup>
- Whether `.*` or `*.*` works (no filter) seems to be platform-dependent; *omitting* `filetypes` is the better option in that case.
- Similarly, the behavior of matching part of the *base* filename - something like `foo.txt` or `foo*.txt` - appears to be platform-dependent: on Windows, these do work, with a prepended `*` (`*foo.txt` and `*foo*.txt`), whereas on macOS they seem to match nothing.

<sup>If the platform-dependent behaviors are instead / also linked to different tkinter versions, do let us know.</sup>

---

<sup>[1] [Jakub Bláha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7047567/jakub-bl%c3%a1ha) reports that `"*.xlsx *.xls"` didn't actually work for him in Python 3.7.4 on Windows 10 version 1903 (though I don't see the same problem); to be safe, omit the `*` if not needed.</sup>

Comment: yeap, this worked.

Answer (score 8):

At least on Windows, if you want to be able to open multiple filetypes but always only one at a time, your code has to look like this:

```
filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Excel file","*.xlsx"),("Excel file 97-2003","*.xls")])
```

If you want to be able to select both file types at the same time without switching between them, they need to have the same name.

```
filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Excel file","*.xlsx"),("Excel file", "*.xls")])
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiple extensions on Windows 10 work for me like this. For example searching for python files.

```
py_exts = r"*.py  *.py3 *.pyc  *.pyo  *.pyw  *.pyx  *.pyd  *.pxd  *.pyi  *.pyi  *.pyz  *.pywz *.rpy  *.pyde *.pyp  *.pyt  *.xpy  *.ipynb"  

filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=SEEN,
                                              title="Select a File",
                                              filetypes=(("video files",
                                                          video_exts),
                                                         ("python files", py_exts),
                                                         ("all files",
                                                          "*.*")))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/",title="Select an Image",filetypes=[("PNG","*.png"),("JPG","*.jpg"),("JPEG","*.jpeg"),("ICON","*.ico")])
```

In order to use multiple file types, you have to add each file type you want to include as an individual 2-tuple combined in list separated by comma. Or if you want to allow all file types you can try: `("All Files","*.*")`.