# Running a python program against a file chosen by tkinter GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I looked everywhere but couldn't quite find an answer.

I have a python program that takes a large CSV and breaks it down and summarizes some metrics. The entire program occurs within a function that takes only the large CSV as a parameter.

I want to use TkInter to open a window that simply has a 'browse' button, and an 'analyze' function. The browse button allows them to select a file from a file dialog. And the analyze button would run my python function with the file chosen.

Is this possible? I am not familiar with TkInter and don't know how to code with it at all.

Comment: yes its possible, use tkinter entry , tkinter button

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9239756/3110529), you can then extend it by adding an analyse button with a callback

Comment: This is a good place to start with tKinter http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/