# How to call a function with arguments in "Button" function from "tkinter" python package?

Tags: python, tkinter

## What i want to do :

**1.To create a File Dialog box with an option to select a file** 
    1.1 First button to select file read its location
      ->Able to do it with the solution provided from below link

[filedialog, tkinter and opening files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9239514/filedialog-tkinter-and-opening-files)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter.messagebox import showerror

class MyFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.master.title("Example")
        self.master.rowconfigure(5, weight=1)
        self.master.columnconfigure(5, weight=1)
        self.grid(sticky=W+E+N+S)

        self.button = Button(self, text="Browse", command=self.load_file, width=10)
        self.button.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)

    def load_file(self):
        fname = askopenfilename(filetypes=(("Template files", "*.tplate"),
                                           ("HTML files", "*.html;*.htm"),
                                           ("All files", "*.*") ))
        if fname:
            try:
                print("""here it comes: self.settings["template"].set(fname)""")
            except:                     # <- naked except is a bad idea
                showerror("Open Source File", "Failed to read file\n'%s'" % fname)
            return


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyFrame().mainloop()
```

**1.2 Second button to start processing** 
->By adding another button to *start*
->Adding a function with argument *process_it*. ->**So function call with argument is not working for my code**

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter.messagebox import showerror

class MyFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.master.title("Example")
        self.master.rowconfigure(5, weight=1)
        self.master.columnconfigure(5, weight=1)
        self.grid(sticky=W+E+N+S)

        self.button = Button(self, text="Browse", command=self.load_file, width=10)
        self.button.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)

        #new code added by me:
        self.button = Button(self, text="Start Now", command=self.process_it(arg_1), width=10)
        self.button.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)

    def load_file(self):
        #new code added by me:
        global arg1 

        fname = askopenfilename(filetypes=(("Template files", "*.tplate"),
                                           ("HTML files", "*.html;*.htm"),
                                           ("All files", "*.*") ))
        #new code added by me:
        arg_1 = fname

        if fname:
            try:
                print("""here it comes: self.settings["template"].set(fname)""")
            except:                     # <- naked except is a bad idea
                showerror("Open Source File", "Failed to read file\n'%s'" % fname)
            return

    # new function added by me:
    def process_it(self, arg_1):
        #use the arg_1 further, example :
        print(arg_1)    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyFrame().mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write factory function to pass some arguments.

```
def command_factory(arg_1):
    def process_it():
        print(arg_1)
    return process_it
```

using

```
Button(self, text="Start Now", command=command_factory(arg_1))
```

or just

```
Button(self, text="Start Now", command=lambda: self.proccess_it(arg_1))
```

But in this case you need to be sure that arg_1 variable is not changing to avoid late binding.

Comment: Thanks, it is working with your provided solution.

Comment: user9318345 mark this as solved.