# How do I save to a specific directory using openpyxl?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, openpyxl

I am trying to save an Excel workbook I created using openpyxl to a specific directory that the user inputs via a Tkinter "browse" button. I have the workbook saving at the inputted "save spot," butI am getting an error saying that it is a directory.

Within the function that is producing the workbook, I have:

```
wb.save(save_spot)
```

The "save spot" is generated via a function:

```
def set_save_destination():
    global save_spot
    save_spot = filedialog.askdirectory()
    save_spot = str(save_spot)
```

The user gets to select the directory by the following Tkinter GUI code, within my GUI class:

```
monthly_browse = ttk.Button(self, text='Select Save Destination', command=set_save_destination)
```

The error message that I receive is an "IsADirectoryError" but I am unsure what the issue is, as is says that you can directly enter the directory into the save method. I am new to programming and completely self-taught, so any help would be great! Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [filedialog-tkinter-and-opening-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9239514)

Comment: Why don't you use `filedialog.asksaveasfilename()` instead of `filedialog.askdirectory()`?

Comment: You don't need to use `global` here, in fact you will probably never need to use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to provide full path to the desired folder please see example below

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()
ws1 = wb.active
ws1.title = "1st Hour"
wb.save('/home/user/Desktop/FileName.xlsx')
```

so you might add additionally filename to the save_spot variable

```
    save_spot = str(save_spot)+'/filename.xlsx'
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I did not realize you had to add the filename at the end of the path

Comment: You are welcome, It pretty easy to mess around sometimes but thankfully python is dynamic typed language so it's easy to fix the code  :)

Comment: Please don't forget to mark the answer as correct one, thank you in advance!